# Flask SocketIO Error during websocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, flask

Trying to run Flask-SocketIO chat app but whenever I try to deploy it on localhost machine it always return the following error on the debugger

```
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400
```

The chrome console return this error:

```
socket.io.min.js:2 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

The following are the client-side script as well as the connection string

```
window.onload = function(){

var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000', {transports: ['websocket']});
var firstConnect = true;
var myUsername = "";

sendButtonListener(socket);

socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.emit('connection event');
});

socket.on('someone connected', function(username, avatar, onlineUsers, onlineUserAvatars){
    console.log(firstConnect)
    if(firstConnect){
        myUsername = username;
        for(var c = 0; c < onlineUsers.length; c++){
            console.log(onlineUsers[c])
            addUserToOnlineDiv(onlineUsers[c], onlineUserAvatars[c]);
        }
        firstConnect = false;
    }
    else{
        addUserToOnlineDiv(username, avatar);
        connectionBroadcast(username, true);
    }
});

socket.on('incoming message', function(message, author, avatar){
    if(author == myUsername){
        addMessageFromSelf(author, avatar, message);
    }
    else{
        addMessageFromOtherUser(author, avatar, message);
    }
});

socket.on('disconnect event', function(username){
    let divToRemove = "." + username + "-user-online-div";
    $(divToRemove).remove();
    connectionBroadcast(username, false)
});
```

};

The server-side socket handler:

```
@socketio.on('connection event')
def connectionEvent():
    newUsername = session.get('username')
    newUseravatar = session.get('avatar')
    socketio.emit('someone connected', (newUsername, newUseravatar,  onlineUsers, onlineUserAvatars))

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
    author = session.get("username")
    avatar = session.get('avatar')
    socketio.emit("incoming message", (msg, author, avatar))

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    username = session['username']
    indexOfUser = onlineUsers.index(username)
    onlineUsers.pop(indexOfUser)
    onlineUserAvatars.pop(indexOfUser)
    session.pop(username, None)
    session.clear()
    socketio.emit('disconnect event', username)
```

Comment: how are you running this? Because if you do flask run you are using Flask's own server, which knows nothing about SocketIO.

Comment: Running it on localhost using PyCharm IDE

Comment: Sorry I just noticed you meant web server. In that case yes I did run it on Flask's default server, I just got it to run after installing eventlet

Comment: @CorvusRex were you able to resolve this?